# Printing content of all files in directory

Tags: python, file, directory

I am trying to go to a directory and print out the content of all files in it.

```
for fn in os.listdir('Z:/HAR_File_Generator/HARS/job_search'):
    print(fn)
```

When I use this code all it does is print out the file names. How can I make it so I can actually get the content of the file? I have seen a lot of ways to possibly do this but I am wondering if there is a way to do it in the same format as I have it. It doesn't make sense to me that I'm not able to get the file content instead of the name. What would make sense to me is doing `fn.read()` and then printing it out but that does not work.

Comment: what do you mean `that does not work`? you can't `with open(fn) as fd: print fd.read()`? or what?

Comment: // , Why are people downvoting this? This question is fine, it's a new user, etc.  I think what you're asking for, Ryan, is something analogous to a recursive Unix `cat` command, right? And it's OK if the output is silly looking?

Comment: The (single) downvote is probably due to the perceived lack of research into how to work with file I/O.

Comment: // , That's where the strange, the forthright, the people who take responsibility for their decisions come in, Ryan. We haven't all bailed.

Comment: // , Speaking of which, you should probably edit the question to answer HuStmpHrrr's concerns. Consider that many more people than you will be reading this.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I realized it did not work because I had not opened it yet. I got it to work by doing with open(file/directory) as fileName

Answer (score 1):

```
directory = 'Z:/HAR_File_Generator/HARS/job_search'
for fn in os.listdir(directory):
   print(open(os.path.join(directory, fn), 'rb').read())
```

Edit: You should probably close your files too but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
mydir = 'Z:/HAR_File_Generator/HARS/job_search'

for fn in os.listdir(mydir):
    print open(mydir+'/'+fn).readlines()
```

Why is your code not printing any file contents? Because you are not reading any file contents.

For printing prettily..

```
for fn in os.listdir(mydir):
    for line in open(mydir+'/'+fn).readlines():
        print line
```

And to avoid this closing issue in case of much much larger files,

```
for fn in os.listdir(mydir):
    with open(mydir+'/'+fn) as fil:
        print fil.readlines()
```

Comment: Just by the way here, but file objects are already iterable, and `readlines()` will `return` a `list`. In the first snippet you could just use `read()` to print the file normally instead of having extra quotes, commas, and brackets; in the second snippet you can omit `.readlines()` entirely; the third snippet can use `read()` instead of `readlines()` just like the first snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they're text files that can actually be printed:

```
dirpath = 'Z:/HAR_File_Generator/HARS/job_search'
for fn in os.listdir(dirpath):
    with open(os.path.join(dirpath, fn), 'r') as f: # open the file
        for line in f: # go through each line
            print(line) # and print it
```

Or, in Python 3 (or Python 2 with the proper import):

```
dirpath = 'Z:/HAR_File_Generator/HARS/job_search'
for fn in os.listdir(dirpath):
    with open(os.path.join(dirpath, fn), 'r') as f: # open the file
        print(*f, sep='') # and send every line to the print function
```